# Rhodecode apache proxy as a subdirectory issue

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtual-machine, rhodecode

I'm running a Ubuntu 12.04 server inside of a vm (vmware) on a Windows Server.  I'm running Rhodecode on the vm.  I can access RhodeCode fine from the host machine via its IPAddress and the port RHodecode is running on (102.168.226.128:5000) but can't access it from another machine on the network.  To fix this I am trying to use an apache proxy as a subdirectory (a coworker suggested this) but am having issues.  I added the following code to production.ini

```
filter-with = proxy-prefix (in [app.main])
```

and

```
[filter:proxy-prefix]
use = egg:PasteDeploy#prefix
prefix = /<rhodecode> (at the end of the file)
```

when i attempt to build the database (sudo paster setup-rhodecode production.ini)
I get the following error:
The section 'main' is not the application (probably a filter).  You should add #section_name, where section_name is the section that configures your application

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you did nothing wrong, but try this in your `production.ini`

```
[filter-app:main]
# instead of filter:proxy-prefix
use = egg:PasteDeploy#prefix
prefix = /scm
next = rh

[app:rh] 
# instead of app:main
use = egg:rhodecode
```

Then generate your setup with

```
paster setup-rhodecode production.ini#rh
```

I had the same problem as described in the question and I stumbled across [a post from Ian Bicking](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/paste-users/upkZU25obeI/kWMez3Tl8DkJ) (that I adapted for the Rhodecode config):

> You have to refer to an [app:*] section with setup-app.  So if you
>   have something like:
>
> ```
> [filter-app:main]
> use = something
> next = myapp
>
> [app:myapp]
> blah
> ```
>
> Then you have to do paster setup-app deploy.ini#myapp